# Drupal 7 - Form Api ajax callback causes Synchronous XMLHttpRequest deprecation

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

I have two forms on my Drupal page, one form is populating its fields when value of the first form is changed (when you choose an item from a select box). It seems to work fine, untill I try to submit the form, which won't do much, since in my browser it says this error:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

```
<?php 

function my_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['form_1'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => "Select box",
        '#collapsible' => FALSE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    ];

    $form['form_1']['id'] = [
        '#title' => t('Choose:') ,
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => [
            '1' => 'ONE',
            '2' => 'TWO',
            '3' => 'THREE'
        ],
        '#required' => '1',
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => 'my_form_state_ajax_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'form_edit',
        ],
    ];

    //--------

    $form['form_2'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => "This is form",
        '#collapsible' => FALSE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#prefix' => '<div id ="form_edit">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['form_2']['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Name',
        '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['form_2']['button'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Create",
        '#submit' => ['my_form_submit'],
    ];

    return $form;

}

function my_form_state_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    $values = $form_state['values'];
    $id = $values['id'];

    if($id > 0) {
        $form['form_2']['name']['#value'] = "this works!";
    } else {
        if(isset($form['form_2']['name']['#value'])) unset($form['form_2']['name']['#value']);
    }

    return $form['form_2'];
}
```

How to fix this error? It doesn't really matter what is inside the callback function, it can be empty and the error will still occur.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the response from the request?

Comment: @Perry I'm sorry, how do I do that? (There is like 15 drupal responses - I don't know what am I looking for)

Comment: You should see the response of your XHR request in your web console. Be sure you openend your web console before the request is made. For Chrome for example; see the network tab

Comment: @Perry In the console, after the action there are 4 new responses (ajax,   jquery.ui.core.min.js, jquery.ba-bbq.js & overlay-parent.js) all 200 OK and in response there are very long pieces of codes. What specific am I looking for? In the ajax response there is just json encoded info about that form

Comment: I was looking for a call for your webform. But maybe you should take a look at this: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2643540